# ¿Cómo buscar una palabra en una lista de caracteres en Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente arreglo y el siguiente string

```
lista1 = ['A','B','C','D','**H**','P','**O**','T','R','**L**','**A**','L','A']
palabra = 'HOLA'
```

¿Cómo haria para que me diga cuantas veces se encuentra la palabra Hola en la lista 1? Tenía en mente recorrer la lista con un for y convertir la palabra en un arreglo de caracteres para así comparar, el problema viene que no se como hacer para que encuentre las coincidencias de la palabra.

```
import csv
Palabra = 'Hola'
l = list(Palabra)

def leer(Archivo):

    with open(Archivo, newline='') as File:   
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        strReader = str(reader).strip('[]')

        conter = 0
        for row in reader:
            for i in range (0,len(l)):
                if l[i] in row:
                    conter = conter + 1

            print('Se encuentran', conter,'Elementos en la fila')
            print(row)
            conter = 0
```

Mi código lee un archivo .csv de un abecedario en desorden; la idea es buscar cuantas veces por fila se encuentra la palabra hola pero no necesariamente tienen que estar seguidas. Por ahora mi código lo que hace es buscar las letras en común de la palabra en cada fila.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Tu pregunta quedaria mucho mejor y seria mas facil ayudarte si compartes el código que tienes hecho o que tienes en mente. Un saludo :)

Comment: El output que esperás es 1?

Comment: Sii, exactamente que en el arreglo se encuentra 1 vez la palabra HOLA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante expresiones regulares puedes conocer cuántas veces una palabra se encuentra en una lista de letras.

En tu ejemplo, tenemos la lista y la palabra de búsqueda.

```
lista1 = ['A','B','C','D','**H**','P','**O**','T','R','**L**','**A**','L','A']
palabra = 'HOLA'
```

Importamos la libreria de expresiones regulares **re**

```
import re
```

Luego formamos nuestra expresión de regular en base a la palabra de búsqueda:

```
regex="("+".*?".join(palabra) + ")"
```

Tomando como ejemplo la palabra HOLA, la expresión regular que formamos con la sentencia anterior es: **(H.*?O.*?L.*?A)**. Esto significa que extraiga una H seguida de una O. Entre la H y la O pueden haber cualquier caracter **(.*)**, sin embargo, necesitamos que sólo avance lo mínimo y necesario a  la O, de lo contrario se va hacia la más lejana. Por tal razón es el signo **?**. Lo que queda como **.*?**. Los paréntesis es para conocer cuantos grupos encontró. Lo mismo entre la O y L y entre esta y la A.

Lo demás es ejecutar es ejecutar la expresión regular, pero antes al arreglo lo convertimos en una cadena:

```
lista1Cadena=" ".join(lista1)
```

Ejecutamos la expresión regular:

```
encontrados = re.finditer(regex, lista1Cadena, re.MULTILINE)
cantidad=len([matchNum for matchNum, match in enumerate(encontrados, start=1)])

print("Se encontraron {} palabra(s) {} en la lista".format(cantidad,palabra))
```

Todo junto queda así:

```
lista1 = ['A','B','C','D','**H**','P','**O**','T','R','**L**','**A**','L','A']
palabra = 'HOLA'

import re

regex="("+".*?".join(palabra) + ")"

lista1Cadena=" ".join(lista1)

encontrados = re.finditer(regex, lista1Cadena, re.MULTILINE)
cantidad=len([matchNum for matchNum, match in enumerate(encontrados, start=1)])

print("Se encontraron {} palabra(s) {} en la lista".format(cantidad,palabra))
```

**Resultado:**
Se encontraron 1 palabra(s) HOLA en la lista

Answer (score 0):

Una solución digamos que un poco aburrida, sería usar *variables* para completar la palabra buscada y cuando la encontramos, reseteamos la palabra hasta que la encontremos de vuelta y así repetir la acción.

Repito, esta solución es muy aburrida y estoy seguro que lloverán respuestas más divertidas y eficientes, ya que es un problema "divertido" de resolver.

```
flag = 0
palabra_auxiliar = ''
output = 0
for char in lista1:

    if char == palabra[flag]:

        palabra_auxiliar+=char
        flag+=1

    if palabra_auxiliar == palabra:

        output+=1
        flag=0
        palabra_auxiliar = ''
print(output)
>> 1
```

Explicación del código:

`flag` es un contador que sirve como índice para buscar el carácter buscado, por ejemplo si `flag` es 0 entonces `palabra[flag]` es `'H'`. Cuando coinciden, agregamos la letra a `palabra_auxiliar`, pasamos a buscar la siguiente letra(en este caso `'O'`) , o sea la posición 1, entonces `flag+=1` va a ayudarnos a buscarla.

Cuando `palabra_auxiliar` se convierte en `palabra`, es decir, `'HOLA'`, va a incrementar la variable `output` (donde guardaremos las *n* veces que se encontrará `palabra`). En este mismo momento debemos resetear las variables para poder encontrar la segunda coincidencia. Y luego mostramos las coincidencias encontradas.

pd: volviendo a tu ejemplo, veo que usas `in`. Debes tener en cuenta que la palabra reservada `in` va a devolver `True` o `False` si encuentra `l[i]` en `row` **sin importar la posición**.

por ejemplo:

```
'H' in 'OAHABO'
True
```

Nos está diciendo que `H` se encuentra en `OAHABO`. Lo cual es correcto pero en este caso nos importa la posición.